# matplotlib: matshow has grid lines on top of image

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm using pyplot.matshow to plot a matrix, and am trying to use `plt.gca().set_axisbelow(True)` to make the gridlines show behind the plot but they are always on top.  How can I make the grid lines plot behind a matshow?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.axisbelow'] = True

m = np.zeros((21, 21))
m[14:17, 12:14] = -0.1

plt.matshow(np.ma.masked_equal(m, 0), cmap=ListedColormap(['k', 'w']), extent=(0.5, 20.5, 20.5, 0.5))
plt.xticks(range(1, 21));
plt.yticks(range(1, 21));
plt.gca().set_axisbelow(True)
plt.grid()
```

Note: edited to plot only nonzero parts as noted in comments.

Comment: I have minor difficulty in understanding the need. Do you want the grid below the `matshow`? If so, what is the purpose of having the grid?

Comment: Hmm.  I get your point.  I'm actually using a B&W color scheme, so that  the nonzero values are black and the zeros plot as white.  I suppose I was thinking of the white as being nothing as opposed to actually having a color, which would mean that what I'm actually asking for is to have the grid between the two colors.  Of course that's ridiculous.  However, if I plot only part of the matrix (the nonzero part), is there a way to get the gridlines below that part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the color of the grid to the same color as the squares (instead of the default dark grey). So, 'black' in the case of the example in the question. (`print(matplotlib.rcparams['grid.color']` shows the default grid color: '#b0b0b0'). That way the grid is invisible over the black parts of the plot.

Experiment with line style and/or line width to make the grid less prominent.

In the code below I changed the image to 20x20 to have the black squares nicely centered and removed the lower xticks. The colors don't need to be black and white, though the grid will only be invisible over the squares of the same color as the grid.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = np.zeros((20, 20))
for i in range(20):
    for j in range(20):
        if 45 <= abs(i-9.5)**2 + abs(j-9.5)**2 <= 65:
            m[i, j] = -0.1

plt.matshow(m, cmap=ListedColormap(['indigo', 'gold']), extent=(0.5, 20.5, 20.5, 0.5))
plt.xticks(range(1, 21))
plt.yticks(range(1, 21))
plt.tick_params(axis='x', bottom=False)
plt.grid(c='indigo', ls=':', lw='0.4')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: That does it!  Thanks, @JohanC